# Replacing cookies in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies, google-chrome-console

I've seen that you can replace cookies file (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies) and change the set of logged in accounts in chrome.

I was wondering if it's possible to do it **in browser using console**.

So far I've tried the following approach and failed

1. Go to google.com
2. Log into google account
3. Get `document.cookie.split(';');` from console.
4. Open an incognito window
5. Go to google.com
6. Set each value of cookie using `document.cookie = 'key=value'`
7. Verified the values are set by running `document.cookie.split(';');` in incognito

Am I missing a step or doing something fundamentally wrong? What's the right way to enter cookie data using console?

Comment: how did you do it in the end?

Comment: @brauliobo I couldn't. Any idea how?